# Implementation of Simple CSRF in Spring Boot and Angular 6 With Complete Solution

Tags: java, cookies, csrf, header

I am Implementing **CSRF** i.e **Cross-Site Request Forgery** in my project but not getting proper way to implement in my project and i am using **Angular** for FrontEnd and **Java** for BackEnd in **Spring Boot** and I tried many resources for solution from the internet but not getting proper way to implement

This is my **Spring Boot** Code

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .csrf() // csrf config starts here
    .ignoringAntMatchers(CSRF_IGNORE) // URI where CSRF check will not be applied
    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()) // defines a repository where tokens are stored
    .and()
    .addFilterAfter(new CustomCsrfFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);// Csrf filter in which we will add the cooki
    //http.csrf().disable();
   }

 private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
     repository.setHeaderName(CustomCsrfFilter.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME);
    return repository;
 }
```

And, This is my **Angular** Code

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpXsrfTokenExtractor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CookieService } from "ngx-cookie-service";

@Injectable()
export class HttpXsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor,private cookieService: CookieService,private cookie: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor, ) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const headerName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
    let token =null;

    const value: string = this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
    console.log(value," <<<<++++ ")

    const allCookies: {} = this.cookieService.getAll();
    console.log("value ==>> ",allCookies)

    token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
    console.log(token, 'this is my xsrf token');

    if (token !== null && !req.headers.has(headerName)) {
      req = req.clone({
          // headers: req.headers.set(headerName, token),
          withCredentials: true
        });
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Not Getting **Cookies**, **Header** or **Token** This is Actual Code where not Getting my XSRF-TOKEN Value and When i tried in PostMan i am getting Token Value in Header as well as in **Cookies**

> My Expectation is I Should able to Read `XSRF-TOKEN` value every time in FrontEnd